# How can I open a file for writing that safely allows other programs to read?

Tags: c#, .net, io, filestream

I'm opening a FileStream and writing lines to it using the following two code snippets:

```
public static System.IO.FileStream OpenFileStream(string FullFilename) {
    return new System.IO.FileStream(FullFilename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
        System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
}

public static void WriteLine(System.IO.FileStream fileStream, string str) {
    fileStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str + "\r\n");
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    fileStream.Flush();
}
```

The file being accessed, i.e. the `FullFilename` parameter in `OpenFileStream`, is a CSV file. Once the file has been opened, the requirement is to be able to see what's been written to the CSV file so far.

I've been using Microsoft Excel for that, and when Excel opens the file, it notices that the file is in use and gives me a dialog box which tells me I can only get read-only access.  Nonetheless, the act of Excel trying to open the file sometimes causes exceptions to be thrown in the program that's got the open FileStream, even though the access that `OpenFileStream` grants to other programs is `System.IO.FileShare.Read`.

The exception that gets thrown is a `System.IO.IOException` with the message `The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file`, and it can get thrown at any point in the `WriteLine` function that accesses the `FileStream`.

**How can I prevent any exceptions ever being thrown by another program like Excel trying to read the file?**

Comment: Can't you copy the content of the filestream to a memorystream so the file isn't being accessed anymore or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I need to be able to see what's been written so far, so I don't think storing in memory helps.

Comment: It seems this is the correct way. The problem is when the file is already open for writing - then you cannot open it for the same.

Comment: @i486 I am not trying to open for writing in Excel, just reading.  However, the act of opening for "read only" is still causing exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: @Stochastically If you first open in Excel, it is open there for reading and writing. You have to open the file first in your app, then in Excel (don't remember whether Excel has "read only" checkbox in Open dialog).

Comment: @i486 Yes, I open first in the app, and then I open for "read only" in Excel.  And that sometimes causes exceptions to be thrown.  If you don't believe me, try for yourself!

Comment: @Stochastically I hope you keep the file open in your prog all the time - not opening and closing for each write.

Comment: @i486 yes I do keep it open all the time, and that's absolutely necessary.  If it I closed the FileStream, then Excel or any other program for that matter could get write access and that would be a disaster.

Comment: Try without `Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)` - the offset has to be at the end by default.

Comment: @i486 that's not good enough because (a) I've seen the exception thrown on other lines, and (b) sometimes the current position isn't at the end.

Comment: @Stochastically The exception says that other application is locking part of file (exclusively). You may catch it and retry the operation. It is strange why Excel is doing this - especially on read-only file.

Comment: @i486 retrying would concern me that the operation was partially completed.  I'm not looking for a "this might work" solution because that not bulletproof, surely there's an expert on stackoverflow that knows how to do this.

Comment: @Stochastically Excel causes the exception with `LockFileEx` (Win32). If you lock the file in the same way (with LockFileEx) maybe will protect it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is everytime write a string to the end of file. To prevent 'hogging' the file you can close the file everytime you write to it.

The default encoding for a StreamWriter is [UTF8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static void WriteLine(string fileName, string str) 
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the FileStream open because it may be needed at a moment's notice and would cause other problems if another process had the file open. To stop the exceptions, I could open it with FileShare.None, but surely there's a way to allow other programs to read what's been written so far without getting any exceptions thrown?

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question. Eventhough you specify that that file can only be read by other processes, it still sometimes give a conflict in your application. It looks like the other process is writing. I found this similar question: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/122783/open-a-file-with-FileShare-Read-does-not-lock-the (No good answer though)

Comment: Yes indeed :-), but in fact the other process is definitely only reading, and that still causes a conflict with an exception thrown in the app that's doing the writing!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @i486 for the clue.  This version of `WriteLine` *seems* to solve the problem:

```
    public static void WriteLine(System.IO.FileStream fileStream, string str) {
        try {
            LockFile(fileStream);
            fileStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str + "\r\n");
            fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fileStream.Flush();
        } finally {
            UnlockFile(fileStream);
        }
    }
    public static void LockFile(System.IO.FileStream fileStream) {
        bool notlocked = true;
        while (notlocked) {
            try { fileStream.Lock(0, long.MaxValue); notlocked = false; } catch (Exception Ex) { ReaperCore.CoreLogging.ExceptionDescription(Ex); }
        }
    }
    public static void UnlockFile(System.IO.FileStream fileStream) { fileStream.Unlock(0, long.MaxValue); }
```

The remaining issue is how to deal with the possibility that a file that's gets read access keeps the file locked, because if that happens, the code above will remain in `LockFile(...)` forever.